# Triple integral of a set $E\subset\mathbb R^3$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the set $$E=\left\{(x,y,z) \in R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 4,{1 \over 3}(x^2+y^2) \le z^2 \le 3(x^2+y^2),z\ge 0\right\} $$ and I want to calculate $$\int_E z(x^2+y^2)\ dx\ dy\ dz.$$

It's better cylindrical or spherical change of coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is better to use cylindrical coordinates. Let
$$ E_1=\left\{(x,y,z) \in R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 4, z^2\le{1 \over 3}(x^2+y^2) ,z\ge 0\right\}$$ 
$$ E_2=\left\{(x,y,z) \in R^3: x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 4,z^2 \le 3(x^2+y^2),z\ge 0\right\}. $$
Then $E=E_2\setminus E_1$. Let $x=r\cos\theta,y=\sin\theta$. So
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_E z(x^2+y^2)\ dx\ dy\ dz&=&\int_{E_2} z(x^2+y^2)\ dx\ dy\ dz-\int_{E_1} z(x^2+y^2)\ dx\ dy\ dz.
\end{eqnarray}
You can do the rest.

Comment: The spherical integration actually looks quite nice too

Comment: $E_1$ in cylindrical coordinates is $\{(r,\theta,z): 0 \le z \le \sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}z \le r \le \sqrt{4-z^2},0\le \theta \le 2\pi\}?$